# When performing query I get object instead of field, in related table in typeorm

Tags: typeorm

These are my tables:

```
@Entity('localidades')
export class Localidades {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({type:"varchar",length:100})
    nombre: string;

    @ManyToOne(type => Provincias)
    @JoinColumn({name: "idprovincia"})
    provincia: string;
    
}

@Entity('provincias')
export class Provincias {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({type:"varchar",length:100})
    nombre: string;
    
}
```

This is my query:

```
 return await this.repository.createQueryBuilder("localidades")
    .select('localidades')
    .addSelect('provincias.nombre')
    .leftJoin('localidades.provincia','provincias')
    .getMany();
```

Obtained result:

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        "nombre": "Ciudad 1",
        "provincia": {
            "nombre": "Provincia 1"
        }
    }
```

Expected result:

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        "nombre": "Ciudad 1",
        "provincia": "Provincia 1"
    }
```

I need province to be returned as a field and not as an object.

Your comments will be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try smth like this:

```
return await this.repository.createQueryBuilder("localidades")
    .select('localidades')
    .addSelect('provincias.nombre')
    .leftJoin('localidades.provincia','provincias')
    .addSelect('provincias.nombre AS localidades_provincia') // select with alias
    .getRawMany();
```

---

UPD:

```
return await this.repository.createQueryBuilder("localidades")
    .leftJoin('localidades.provincia','provincias')
    .select([
      'localidades.id AS localidades_id',
      'localidades.nombre AS localidades_nombre',
      'provincias.nombre AS localidades_idprovincia',
      'provincias.nombre AS localidades_provincia'
    ]).getRawMany();
```

Comment: That partly worked. Now it looks like this: `"localidades_id": 1,
        "localidades_nombre": "Ciudad 1",
        "localidades_idprovincia": 1,
        "provincia": "Provincia 1" `

Comment: The ideal would be: `"id": 1,"nombre": "Ciudad 1","idprovincia": 1,"provincia": "Provincia 1" `

Comment: If I use `.getMany ()` instead of `.getRawMany ()` it doesn't show the province field

Comment: Ok, that's how it finally turned out. `return await this.repository.createQueryBuilder("localidades")
    .select([
      'localidades.id AS id',
      'localidades.nombre AS nombre',
      'provincias.nombre AS provincia'])
    .leftJoin('localidades.provincia','provincias')
    .getRawMany();`